# Pygame has input lag when using pygame.time.delay()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame-clock

My goal for my program is for it to loop over images and display them on the screen. When the user presses space, it is supposed goes to a new screen. For some reason, there is a lag from when the user presses space and when it breaks out of the game1 loop.

```
def game_loop1():
        game1=True
        winScreen=True
        current=0
        myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 25)
        label = myfont.render("Who is this person? (Press Space)", 1, (0,0,0))


    while game1:
            for event in pygame.event.get():

                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                   pygame.quit()
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key==pygame.K_SPACE:
                       game1=False # doesn't break out of loop immediately here
        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        gameDisplay.blit(label,(0,500))
        gameDisplay.blit(obama[current], (0,0))
        current+=1
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(50)
        pygame.time.delay(2500)


    while winScreen:
        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        winLabel=myfont.render("The person was Obama! ", 1, (0,0,0))
        gameDisplay.blit(winLabel,(0,500))
        gameDisplay.blit(obama[len(obama)-1], (0,0))
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.delay(2500)
        winScreen=False
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Why are you using `pygame.time.delay(2500)`

Comment: The time delay is stoping pygame from giving you new events (quit) until it is over. You should change your loop to switch to a new picture once a button is pressed and the time is a specified amount later.

Comment: Why would it break out of the loop immediately when you set `game1=False`? the condition for the loop isn't re-evaluated until the current iteration is done (and you have a delay call added at the end of the loop, so the re-evaluation is obviously delayed)

Comment: `delay` is not good solution because it delays program not only after it sets `game = False` but it delays `for event` loop. It checks pressed key only every 2.5s.

Comment: As others have pointed out, delaying is a bad idea.  Have a variable that stores the time when you start and check each time through the loop to see if you should move on.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
game1=False
break
```

to exit the while loop immediately.

However, in this case you don't really need the `game1` variable. You could change the loop condition to `True`, and replace the line `game1=False` with `break`, and your code should work as expected.